# What is the difference between standalone and desktop application?

Tags: operating-system

I searched it a lot, I found everyone saying that standalone application does not require operating system services but how a software can function without using operating system services. Like if you take NetBeans , even the platform independent version of NetBeans ultimately takes the operating system services in backend.

Moreover if we talk about notepad, is it a standalone or desktop application.

Is eclipse(an IDE) a standalone or desktop application.

Please help I am really confused

Comment: Q: Who is "everyone"???  Two possible definitions are [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standalone_program) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845451/technical-difference-between-a-stand-alone-app-vs-web-app).  If you take the first, Wikipedia, definition, then *NO* Windows program - and relatively few embedded applications - are truly "standalone".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Standalone vs. Desktop application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17592791/standalone-vs-desktop-application)

Answer (score 1):

From the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standalone_program)

> A stand-alone program is a computer program that does not load any
>   external module, library function or program and that is designed to
>   boot with the bootstrap procedure of the target processor

So to answer your question about `netbeans` or `notepad` both of them definitely requires some `OS` intervention to run. In order to write your standalone application you will need to rewire a bunch of low level stuff including the loader. The nuisances involved are usually  not worth the benefit they achieve in era of modern programming frameworks and ever growing faster hardware. The same wiki article mentions that `standalone applications are almost extinct now`

> but how a software can function without using operating system services

Well to function, the software will just need to mimic some of the operating system services it requires. some [device drivers](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/usenix99/full_papers/tso/tso.pdf) do  exactly that. Though the definition of `standalone programs` is itself fuzzy, some embedded softwares tend to fall in the category of the definition from the wiki page.